# convert an application iPad in a iPhone (how to make...the popover)

Tags: xcode4

I have an iPad application that opens a box by pressing a button that works as a popover. would be possible to convert it into a iphone application where when I press the button opens a full screen view specific?

Comment: how do I open a view by pressing a button?

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments you should checkout following tutorial:
http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/iphone-imagebuttonchangeview.html

Kind regards,
Bo